# C unsigned int + int

Tags: c, int, unsigned

Why does this code print `"greater than 0"`?

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int a = 5;
  int b = -10;
  (a + b) > 0 ? printf("greater than 0") : printf("less than 0");
}
```

If I do:

```
printf("%d\n", a + b);
```

...it prints:

```
-5
```

Comment: Integer promotion rules.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", a + b);` actually has undefined behavior. The result of `a + b` is of type `unsigned int`, but `"%d"` requires an argument of type `int`. It's OK if the value is within the range of but types, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you do any operation in C, the arguments are converted according to the "Usual arithemetic conversions" rules (section 6.3.1.8 of the spec).  There are lots of them, but for the purposes of this example, the important one is:

> the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>   following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>   If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>   Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>   Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.

`int` and `unsigned int` have the same coversion rank, so whenever you do an operation on an `int` and an `unsigned int`, the `int` will be converted to `unsigned`.

In you case, that causes the value of b (-10) to become a very large number.  You then add 5 to it, which is still very large (but not large enough to wrap around back to zero), so the result of `>` is true.

Comment: You might want to explain the UB too.

Comment: The actual value of `-10` when converted to `unsigned` is equal to `UINT_MAX - 9` where `UINT_MAX` is available in `<limits.h>` and represents the maximum (implementation-defined) value that an `unsigned` can represent.     Also, the reason `a + b` gives a positive value is not related to wrapping - it is because it has an `unsigned` result which can never be negative.

Comment: @Peter -- while an unsigned value will never be negative, it might be zero, so the comparison can't be ignored for type reasons -- it still has to be performed (perhaps at compile time as a constant fold, as all the operands here are constants).

Comment: @ChrisDodd -  I didn't suggest otherwise.   The OP was clearly expecting an output of "less than 0" given the inputs.   The inputs would not produce a zero result under any circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

[6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) and [6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) (thanks Chris)

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
>   integer promotions.58) All other types are unchanged by the integer
>   promotions.

and

> ...if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand
>   with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with
>   unsigned integer type.

You addition involves an `unsigned` and an `int`, `int` cannot represent all values of `unsigned`, so the value is converted to an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

## Your problem

By default, your `int` gets promoted to an `unsigned int`, according to the [usual arithmetic conversions](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.1.8.html):

> [...] if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.

## Solution

You need to cast `a` to `int` for this ternary to work as you expect:

```
((int)a + b) > 0 ? printf("greater than 0") : printf("less than 0");
```

Answer (score -1):

In your print statement, you are converting a and b to their signed int representation before you add them together. You are not doing so for your conditional.